# create plot with ajax and json, then get variables - jqplot

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc, jqplot

what I want is to get these variables with json in an event of a button and ajax to create the plot.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var s1 = [4, 9, 15];
var s2 = [,,,8];
var s3 = [3, 4, 12, 16];

var ticks = ['2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'];
var seriesColorsTicks = ['#85802b','#73C774','#00749F'];
var seriesColors1 = ['#85802b', '#73C774', '#85802b', '#85802b'];
var seriesColors2 = ['#73C774', '#73C774', '#73C774', '#73C774'];
var seriesColors3 = ['#00749F', '#00749F', '#00749F', '#00749F'];

var plot4 = $.jqplot('chart4', [s1,s2,s3], {
    title: 'Grafico de ejemplo',
    animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            ticks : ticks
        },
        yaxis: {
            autoscale:true,
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
        }
    },
    seriesColors: seriesColorsTicks,
    series: [
        {seriesColors:seriesColors1, label:'s1', renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer},
        {seriesColors:seriesColors2, label: 's2', renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer},
        {seriesColors:seriesColors3, label: 's3'},
    ],
```

.....

```
});
```

});

Comment: did you get your solution? can you share?

Comment: Yes... send message for me.